# How to automatically import remote XML data into FileMaker?

Tags: xml, filemaker

I'm using FileMaker Pro 13 and would like to automate the importing of remote XML data. These imports will both add and update records based on a unique ID.

I already have a valid XML feed and XSLT file but cannot find any way to automate the import of this web accessible XML data.

I can accomplish the import successfully, but only manually.

- "File->Import Records->XML Data Source..." -- Does not have a recurring
  option.
- "File->Import Records->File" -- Cannot use HTTP and cannot read
  XML.

Is this possible with FMP13? If so, how?

Comment: Why don't you **script** this?

Comment: That would be a perfect solution. The problem I kept running into was it seems that I cannot use HTTP to fetch the data. http://www.filemaker.com/help/11/fmp/html/scripts_ref1.36.68.html Is this now possible in FMP 13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I kept running into was it seems that I cannot use HTTP to
>   fetch the data. filemaker.com/help/11/fmp/html/scripts_ref1.36.68.html
>   Is this now possible in FMP 13?

It is possible now, and it was always possible (ever since version 6, when XML import was first introduced). From the above page:

> The XML and XSLT source may be a file or **the result of an HTTP
>   request**, or a calculation that generates a file path or **an HTTP
>   request**.

The script step you need to use is Import Records. Under 'Specify data source' select `XML Data…`, then, under 'Specify XML data source' select `HTTP request:` and enter your URL into the text box (or calculate it using the `Calculation` option).